# Shell script to test delimiter characters in file names

Tags: unix, shell

thanks for reading & your suggestions. I'm moving files into respective directories, only some of the files use `_` and some use `-` (underscore and hyphen) as delimiters. Is there a way to test for the different delimiters?

E.g.:

```
ParentDir
    1897/
    1898/
    1994summer/
    file-1897-001.txt
    file-1897-002.txt
    file-1898-001.txt
    file-1898-002.txt
    file_1994summer_001.txt
    file_1994summer_002.txt
```

I've been processing with the following (verbose so I can understand it) shell script:

```
!/bin/sh
for f in *.jp2
do
base=${f%.txt}
echo "base fileName is $base"
fileName=`echo "$base" | cut -f 2 -d _`
echo "truncated fileName is $fileName"
dir=$fileName
echo "Directory is $dir"
mv -v "$f" "$dir"
sleep 1
done
```

When using the cut command, I'd like to be able to differentiate on the delimiter. Is that possible? Thanks in advance for your time & suggestions.
Cheers!

Comment: `case ${fName} in *_* ) underscore_processing ${fName} ;; *-* ) hyphen_process ${fName} ;; * ) all_other_processing ${fName} ;; esac` . Good luck.

Comment: for portability purposes, i'd like to keep the current she-bang, i.e. `#!/bin/sh`. I've found some other suggestions that require bash -- is there a workaround to keep this entirely Bourne shell?

Comment: hi @shellter -- thanks for the response! i'll test it straight away.

Comment: @shellter's anwser seems to be working just fine. thanks again! (time to read about case) :)

Comment: @shellter, put that as a answer so you can get the appropriate credit.

Comment: @CanOfBees, while you're learning about [case](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) also read about [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) which is what `case` uses for the patterns.

Comment: @glennjackman i know a bit about it -- mostly that it's powerful (and i don't know much about it). thanks for the advice - cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case "${fName}" in 
    *_* ) underscore_funnyFace_processing "${fName}" ;; 
    *-* ) hyphen_funnyFace_process "${fName}" ;; 
    * ) all_other_processing "${fName}" ;; 
esac
```

I'm almost sure bourne shell supported case processing. Don't have access to one to test with.

The difference between bourne/bash/ksh/zsh would be in the shell wildcards patterns that each shell has as an extension to the basic patterns the bourne shell supported.

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi shellter, yes! this is *extremely* helpful (and educational). thanks (again) for the answer!

Comment: Yup, this is fine vanilla sh.  You should really pu double-quotes around `"${fName}"` everywhere, though.

Comment: @MarkReed : yep, you're right. Edited answer. Was/Am in a hurry today. Thanks for making it better. Good luck to all.